# Ember component lookup/debug/testing

Tags: javascript, debugging, testing, ember.js, lookup

How can I access ember component's controller from another controller?
Is there a backdoor way like `__container__.lookup` just to know that there is this instance of component?
When I tried `__container__.lookup` with `"component:<myComponentname>"` it gave me an instance of component which is not being used anywhere in the application.

TL;DR
How to test Ember Component objects?

Comment: Dirty hack which I'm following as of now... is I'm getting the id of the div containing the container and accessing its instance from Ember.View.views["ember_id_"]

Comment: So you basically want to access a controller from another controller? Is that right?

Comment: A specific component instance's controller not any other normal controller.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853826/how-to-get-a-reference-on-a-view-instance-in-ember-emberjs-from-static-javascr

Answer (score 2):

[These lines](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/blob/13b6496864edeaa6b4d53916f7465d87ec96f842/ember_debug/view-debug.js#L610-L612) of [ember-inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector/) reveal how to get a "view registry," a mapping of DOM element ids to their respective `Ember.Component` instance in Ember 2.x, or `Ember.View` instance in 1.x.

```
viewRegistry: computed('application', function() {
  return this.get('application.__container__').lookup('-view-registry:main') || View.views;
}),
```

So if you have an Ember component in your DOM like

```
<span id="ember1234">Hi I'm controlled by Ember</span>
```

you can look it up like

```
var viewRegistry = application.__container__.lookup('-view-registry:main') || View.views;
var myComponentInstance = viewRegistry.ember1234;
```

Comment: Do you know the Ember 4 way of doing this?