# Dynamically load/reload binding data on Ember Timeline

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am using the Ember Timetree code ([Timetree](http://crowdstrike.github.io/ember-timetree/)) and I think it is great. I am a newbie to Ember and D3 so jumping into the Timetree code made my head hurt.
I am trying to add functionality so that if a user clicks a button on the page, the timetree will reload with different data. I have been trying for a while but nothing seems to work.
Here is what I have:

Ember template for the timetree:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="example">
    {{view Ember.Timetree.TimetreeView contentBinding="App.ApiData" selectionBinding="selectedEvents" rangeBinding="eventsRange_example2"}}
  </div>  
</script>
```

HTML that defines the timetree div:

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

HTML for the button the user clicks:

```
<button type="button" onclick="loadNewTimetree()">Reload</button>
```

Javascript for the function to reload the timetree:

```
function loadNewTimetree() {
  var newJsonData = .... Get the JSON data
  // Replace the existing JSON data with the newJsonData and re-draw the timeline - how? 
 }
```

What is the piece I am missing that links the updated JSON to timetree?

Thanks.

Marshall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
First, I added a **viewName="mmView"** tag to my Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div class="example">
    {{view Custom.Timetree.TimetreeView viewName="mmView" contentBinding="App.ApiData" selectionBinding="selectedEvents" rangeBinding="eventsRange_example2"}}
  </div>  
</script>
```

I found the core of the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853826/how-to-get-a-reference-on-a-view-instance-in-ember-emberjs-from-static-javascr). So I updated my javascript function:

```
function loadNewTimetree() {
  var newJsonData = .... Get the JSON data
  // View.views returns a hashtable. Key is the id, value if the View.
  var views = Ember.View.views;

  for (var nextKey in views) {
    var nextView = views[nextKey];
    // The 'viewName' is set in the template and needs to be unique for each timeline.
    if (nextView.viewName && nextView.viewName == 'mmView')
    {
        nextView.reloadWithNewData(newJsonData );
    }
  }

 }
```

Then I added a function in my View to handle the updated JSON:

```
Custom.Timetree.TimetreeView = Ember.Timetree.TimetreeView.extend(
{
... Other attributes,
 reloadWithNewData:function (newTimelineJson) 
 {
   // Need to clear out the svg contents before adding the new content
   // or else you get strange behavior.
   var thisSvg = this.get('svg');
   thisSvg.text('');
   this.set('content', newTimelineJson);
   this.didInsertElement();
}
});
```

So when I call the loadNewTimetree() function, it updates the timeline with the new JSON.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be that you are not doing things the Ember way - which is very different but awesome.  In Ember the button would typically be defined as

```
<button {{action 'loadNewTimeTree'}}>Reload</button>
```

and then in your view or controller one would have an action handler that would loadNewTimeTree. Typically by loading the data into an ember model.

```
App.IndexView = Ember.View.extend({
   actions: {
       loadNewTimeTree: function () {
           var newJsonData = .... //Get the JSON data or more typical
           this.get('controller.model').reload(); //typically JSON handled by RESTAdapter
        }
    }
});
```

If you want to learn the ember way which may be challenging I recommend studying their [website](http://emberjs.com/guides/)

Comment: Thanks. That sheds more light on my problem. In reality, I have a Primefaces application and the javascript function gets called by a Primefaces push event, so there is no user interaction and no button. I'll look for a way to call {{action 'loadNewTimeTree'}} where there is no user interactions. Thanks again.

Comment: If you want to use ember to automate actions have a look at the [run loop](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.run.html) which also allows code to run periodically.